# Possible value of $m$ and $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given that 
If for every $f$ and $g$ non trivial homomorphism from $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{m \mathbb{Z}} \to S_n$ There exist $\sigma$ such that

> $$f(x)=\sigma g(x) \sigma^{-1}$$ 
>   for all $x $ in $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{m\mathbb{Z}}$ Then the possible choice of $m,n$ is ?
>
> $1)3$ and $7$
>
> $2).5$ and $5$
>
> $3).6$ and $4$
>
> $4).6$ and $5$

The solution i tried-Here it is given that $f(x)=\sigma g(x) \sigma^{-1}$ so from this it is clear that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ belongs to same conjugacy class.But this doesnot taking me any where,please provide me hint so that i can proccede further.

Edit- by solving further i see that every subgroup of $Z_m$ is normal so By FHT only posibilty of answer is option $3$ and $4$ but next i don't know how to go further

Comment: Note that $6$ is composite so that $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ has non-isomorphic quotients.

Comment: What does FHT stand for, please?

Comment: first homomorphism theorem

Comment: @EdwardH. where to use that given condition?